# redirect from not-www to www prestashop .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my prestashop website. For some reasons, if I put in the domain name "www.mysite.com" some modules stop working. So, I have to use "mysite.com". Problem is that I want to be displayed www.mysite.com on the browser. I know that there is set of rules to be added to .htaccess to redirect not-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this doesn't work with the rewritebase on prestashop's .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

how can I merge the two rules?

Thank you very much

Comment: Where is the htaccess file located?

Comment: on public_html folder

Comment: I don't think this is apache related. These type of PHP scripts set the domain name in the settings/database. You probably have it set as domain.com for the shop URL. Read this http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Setting+a+shop's+URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this default .htaccess file 
[Default htaccess file](http://allhtaccess.info/prestashop-default-htaccess-file/)

and also check if mod rewrite is enable. If this is not working you can do a 301 redirection to www version.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```